# How to test lambda function against a localhost running application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am playing around with AWS and my main goal is to use a java lambda function to send a SOAP request to a SOAP UI mocking project.

At the moment, if I run the code in Eclipse I do manage to send a request successfully since I'm getting a SOAP response.

However, if I upload the code to the lambda funcion, I got a Connection refused error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Btw, my lambda function has no VPC configuration.

Anyone have any clue how can i test my lambda function code against my SOAP UI mock project?

Thank you so much in advance for any tip :)

Comment: Is your mock project running locally? That might be possible, but will be a lot of work. You need to put the lambda into a VPC, and then [connect yourself to the VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-vpc/) and then configure the routing tables in that VPC / its subnets to somehow direct some of the traffic towards your own machine and make sure your firewall does not block this, etc. This will NOT be fun unless you have a lot of AWS networking experience - if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a hard requirement for you to run the lambda in AWS for testing purposes and [@luk2302](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442804/luk2302) already mentioned it is quite some effort to get the networking going in the right direction.

You can actually run your lambda locally and test with your UI.

There is a lambda docker image for `java` runtime published by AWS in [gallery.ecr.aws](https://gallery.ecr.aws/lambda/java)

Package your code locally using the provided base image:

```sh
docker build -t <image name> .
```

To run your image locally:

```sh
docker run -p 9000:8080 <image name>
```

In a separate terminal, you can then locally invoke the function using cURL:

```sh
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{"payload":"hello world!"}'
```

Another option would be to use [LocalStack - A fully functional local AWS cloud stack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack)

Comment: Basically, my goal is to use a lambda function to perfoms requests against an external third-party webservice every 10min and save the payload in dynamoDB. But since I am just playing around, as my first step I have thought about using SOAP UI to mock data and simulate the request to the external webservice.

Comment: @NelsonDias in your code you still can make requests to third parties provided the endpoint is not restricted to a certain IP address or the networking is in such a way that it can not be invoked outside of AWS.

Comment: @NelsonDias well, external third party services are something COMPLETELY different than a locally 
hosted service. At that point your lambda simply needs to call some api in the internet, that should not be a problem at all.

Comment: for testing purposes my idea was to perform some requests against SOAP UI or a Spring boot application running on my laptop. To be honest, thought it was far more easy to do it.

Comment: @NelsonDias with building container images for lambda and testing with the same. It is going in the correct path and may give you an edge when anyone wants to test the app or you want to run unit test cases in your build environment. Anyways take your pick.